# cleanup "use" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[use](/questions/tagged/use) is on 141 questions on SO; the 23 also tagged [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) are probably legitimate (`use` is apparently also a keyword in Ada, but none of these are tagged [ada](/questions/tagged/ada)), but the rest of them need to go.

Is it possible to automate a cleanup like this where there is a clear criteria for valid/invalid use of a tag, or would the awful uses need to be manually removed?

EDIT: We probably don't need a tag for the Perl keyword, I suggest burnination instead.

Comment: Do we even really need a tag dedicated to a specific keyword in a specific language? Just kill 'em al... wrong website... just burninate.

Comment: No, unfortunately there's no way to clean up a subset of tags based on a filter. They have to be cleaned up manually, or all deleted at once.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: well, I suppose 23 uses of a tag for a keyword that's used in nearly ever Perl script ever written (and for which no one's bothered to write a tag wiki) is a pretty good argument that it can be burninated.

Comment: [tag:use] is a keyword in quite a lot of languages... not just Perl and Ada, for instance PHP, SQL, Ruby, Groovy, F# and Fortran...